# How to mock location during a presentation on a real device?

Tags: android, location

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device) post about mocking location with custom provider, but I am looking for a way to mock the location during a presentation, is that possible?

Comment: not talking about Android specifically nor location specifically, but can't you *always* mock by creating your own wrapping interface around any class you want to mock?  I've done this a lot of time when working with APIs that didn't provide easy way to mock.

Comment: That's doable. For now I've found an app that mocks the location. It's easier to use that for now.

Comment: You might post info on the app as an answer, for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an app that is called [Location Spoofer](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ajeje-fakelocation-CzDx.aspx)