# adb shell: telnet command doesn't work

Tags: android, shell, gps, emulation, adb

i want to learn how to mock up location in android device and develop a location based app. My problem is when I say adb shell in the command prompt it lets me go into the emulator with # symbol.

problem starts here

When I enter telnet localhost 5554 to telnet the device it says telnet: not found

what could be the problem?? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to telnet with adb. Just use a normal command line window to type in telnet localhost 5554 - but don't enter adb before!

Comment: thanks. Telnet didn't work either in command prompt untill I enabled it via <a href="http://www.techexams.net/forums/windows-vista-exams/21897-telnet-will-not-work-my-command-prompt.html#post144038">control panel</a> :)  Thanks a lot for the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have telnet installed.

In ubuntu install it by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install telnet
```

Comment: In an android shell the command set is very limited - that is why telnet isn't available. Neither is sudo and especially not apt-get.

Comment: @omahena precisely, these are commands for the host not for the android device