# GPS - how to set mock-location in Basic4android?

Tags: android, mocking, gps, basic4android

GPS - how to set mock-location in Basic4android ?

how can we set the GPS location ?

Why?

to show a waypoint (52.5 , 13.44)  (Berlin , Schlesische Str.)

in my OFFLINE Navigon and Sygig Navigation Program -WITHOUT internet and google-maps

this apps can do FakeLocation:

search: www.market.android.com/search?q=FakeGPS&so=1&c=apps

MyFakeLocation (www.market.android.com/search?q=MyFakeLocation&so=1&c=apps)

FakeGPS (www.market.android.com/search?q=FakeGPS&so=1&c=apps)

how to set mock-location in my Basic4android ?

GPS-example-Basic4android: http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/6592-gps-tutorial.html

I add  in GPS tutorial FakeLat As Double and FakeLon As Double
 but it do not show my Fake Location

```
Sub Globals
  Dim lblLon As Label
  Dim lblLat As Label
  Dim lblSpeed As Label
  Dim lblSatellites As Label
   '// qq66yy my
  Dim FakeLat As Double
  Dim FakeLon As Double
   '// qq66yy end
End Sub

Sub GPS_LocationChanged (Location1 As Location)
   '// qq66yy my
  FakeLat = 52.5
  FakeLon = 13.44
  Location1.Latitude = FakeLat
  Location1.Longitude = FakeLon
   '// qq66yy end
  lblLat.Text = "f Lat: " & Location1.ConvertToMinutes(Location1.Latitude)
  lblLon.Text = "f Lon: " & Location1.ConvertToMinutes(Location1.Longitude)
  lblSpeed.Text = "V:  " & Location1.Speed
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need the mock service to show a specific point?

Comment: @Erel ____  so, I  can use any offline car navi ( like tomtom , navigon ..) to show locations offline, without internet

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse IDE you can use the DDMS perspective to simulate fake locations and phone events.

I would recommend that you install your B4A app onto a device or an emulator, then start up Eclipse and the DDMS perspective. Then start your app by clicking on the icon and you should be able to simulate locations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071625/using-a-mock-location-in-navigation-app

Comment: see links and a zip for download MockLocationProvider app   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device