# How to change coordinates value in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an app which takes users current location and make changes in the coordinates. I am simply trying to fake users current location but i don't know how should i change coordinates. can i simply just add some value to the latitude and longitude like this:

```
newlongitude=currentlongitude+0.01000;
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the android docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html.

Comment: I know how to use location manger and all that. I am just trying to  take users current location and move user location little bit every time when user clicks button . But i don't know what will be the exact coordinates. so if i just add some value to the current location  like this:  newlongitude=currentlongitude+0.01000;                                                            so is it a right way for changing coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

You can only emulate a new location. Basically you have to pass the values of the new location to Location instance and set Manager Location with Location instance.

I think this can help you:

[Access Mock Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)

[Use Mock Location in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071625/using-a-mock-location-in-navigation-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)