# How to send GPS positions to my phone (with eclipse) to test a GPS application without exit from home?

Tags: android, gps

I need to send GPS positions to my phone (with eclipse) to test a GPS application without exit from home?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried this?  Why isn't it working?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ddms can do that with the emulator, i THINK it will work with a real phone
[image]

Comment: on the phone, you'll need to add the option to recieve mock locations. I don't remember where it is, but it's near the options for usb debugging and developer modes (these need to be enabled as well).