# Fake location using XML #Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an android app where i need to make fake locations at different timings. Is this possible to do this by pushing XML to a android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse with the Android ADT tools installed, you can switch to the DDMS perspective and under the emulator control options, there are geolocation settings.  You can send a single location or use a GPX or KML file to "play back" a series of locations (to simulate driving a route, for example)

You can create KML routes in apps like Google Earth, or code it by hand in XML.  Sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html

There's also an emulator called Genymotion that runs on VirtualBox that has APIS for things like location simulation.  I've been using it for a few weeks now and I'm very impressed:

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Thanks @AWT not sure how can i code it in XML at different location with different timings!

Comment: This tutorial on KML is a good start: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/mobile/providing-gps-coordinates-via-the-eclipse-android-simulator.html.  If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept.  Thanks!

Comment: Also updated the original answer, you might want to look into the Genymotion emulator as well.

Comment: i don't think genymotion can simulate driving a route

Comment: It has an API you can call from outside of the emulator that allows you to set coordinates within the emulator.  If you had a shell script with delays, or a simple java program, you could easily send a sequence of coordinates with a delay between each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mock location provider. In your case you could probably have a class in control of the mock provider that feeds data based on some xml file input.

See:
[Android mock location on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)

It would be easy to implement an interface and switch between live and mock providers. This would allow runtime mocking which I assume is what you are asking for.

Comment: yes i am looking for run time mocking but still confused