# fake gps applications on android (how it works)

Tags: java, android

I have been looking into these Fake GPS applications that are available for download in the android application store.

My question is, how does the application force the fake GPS to be used by other third party applications over the real GPS the phone is collecting.

So GPS is turned on and Fake GPS is enabled in a fake location... What/where decides the GPS coordinates to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android mock location on device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)

Comment: Doesn't say HOW it works... I want to know what the application is Editting on core files or how the system is prioritising the fakeGps over the real gps

Comment: You could just look at the source to see how its handled: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/location/java/android/location/LocationManager.java

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable "Mock Location" on Android developer settings and at some Android versions tell what apps can tell the GPS location. If that is enabled then first is checked what is the GPS location that the "developer" wants to be before checking the actual location.