# How to set location of Android device by programming

Tags: android, gps, location

Is there any way to set location of an Android device by programming?

I mean, I want to manually provide latitude and longitude to my device(REAL, NO EMULATOR). My device doesn't have GPS Hardware.

Is it possible or we have to use something like Mock Location ?

Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DDMS tool to provide fake locations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com) and there is the guide you can use to test different location https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide

Comment: try this if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device

Comment: Link only. At the very least this should include an example

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Eclipse` ,

**Step 1:**

you should go on **Window > Open Perspective > DDMS**

**Step 2:**

inside **DDMS** tab, you should click on **Emulator Control**

**Step 3:**

see **Location Controls** and **send your desired latitude-longitude** to the device

**EDIT :**

If you want to use Mock location programmatically, you may checkout  [Android-MockProviderGPS](https://github.com/paulhoux/Android-MockProviderGPS) project which uses following permission and provide mock locations on each predefined interval from its .csv file from asset folder.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I want to do this on a REAL DEVICE, NOT EMULATOR! Sorry Sir!, but very thanks for reply.

Comment: @RaviPrakash: While doing above process, you should try by keeping selection on your device in `devices tab`