# How to is the JSON string to refill to get new Data

Tags: android, json

I am trying to send JSON string `{"latitude":53.86897577,"longitude":10.66560449,"formatted":"24.04.2015 16:26:35","route":4}` to the server every 60 seconds but I am always getting the same data. How can I manage it to  get always new data in the JSON string. I tried to set timer but without success. I can see the data in the xml file how they are changing but how to realize that with serliziation ?

MainActivity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        int route_number;
        double pLong;
        double pLat;
        String formatted;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
            enableGPS(lm);

          PostData sender = new PostData();
        }   

     class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        if (location != null) {
            pLong = location.getLongitude();
            pLat = location.getLatitude();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                    java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            formatted = sdf.format(location.getTime());

        }
                 String jSONString=  convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);

                 sender.timer(jSONString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

    private String convertToJSON(double pLong, double pLat, String formatted) {
        //envelop the data in JSON format.                  
        Data d = new Data(pLat, pLong, formatted,route_number);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataSerializer()).create();
         //return gson.toJson(d);
         String a = gson.toJson(d);
        // System.out.println(a);
         return a;
    }
    }
```

PostData class:

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public PostData() {
        super();


    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;
    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void timer(String jSONString) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean run = true;
                while (run) {
                   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
                       }
                   }, 30000);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground " +jSONString);

            return null;

        }

    }

}

}
```

Passed JSON String with fourth key which I am getting from the inner class BroadcastReceiver in my MainActivity:

```
{
  "latitude":53.86897577,
  "longitude":10.66560449,
  "formatted":"24.04.2015 16:26:35",
  "route":4

}
```

Comment: you will receive the new location in your `ll` listener. Are you setting the new values in there?

Comment: please update your question this the code

Comment: @ Deividi Cavarzan: please see the code of the updated question.

Comment: are you receiving the call to `onLocationChanged`?

Comment: Is your location actually changing? If not `onLocationChanged` won't be called.

Comment: @Kalem no my location is not changing I am setting on my desk :D I think this is the problem right?

Comment: @ Deividi Cavarzan: I can see in my xml file how the time is changing but the Long and lat are not changing.

Comment: I think you guess right ;) You can simulate location see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device

Comment: But your device is moving? If not, probably you will get the same LatLng always

Comment: @Deividi Cavarzan: No the device is connected to the laptop with the usb cabel but I tried to set the Thread part in the onCreate in onLocationChanged but nothing has changed and I am still getting the same time in the JSON string?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need in initiate a call to `timer()` in `onLocationChanged()`.  Just change `timer()` to take the `jSONString` instead of setting it in the constructor.

The other main issue is that you should reference the `varargs` passed into your `AsyncTask`.

Note that what I'm proposing here removes your background `Thread`, and only sends data to the server when the location changes.

Note that you will need to walk around to get the `onLocationChanged()` events to happen.

I assume you will be adding code to send the `jSONString` to your server in your `AsyncTask`, and that looks good.

First, fix your `AsyncTask`:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground " +jSONString);
        System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground " +params[0]); //use the first index of params

        return null;
    }
}
```

In the `timer()` method, add `jSONString` as a parameter, and remove the parameter from your constructor:

```
public PostData() {
    super();
}

public String getjSONString() {
    return jSONString;
}

public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
    this.jSONString = jSONString;
}

public void timer(String jSONString) {
     this.jSONString = jSONString; //add this here
     new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
}
```

onLocationChanged method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        pLong = location.getLongitude();
        pLat = location.getLatitude();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
        formatted = sdf.format(location.getTime());

        //add code below:
        String jSONString=  convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);

        sender.timer(jSONString);
    }
}
```

Then in `MainActivity`, just intialize `PostData`, but don't call `timer` because you don't have location data yet:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, ll);
enableGPS(lm);

PostData sender = new PostData(); //just initialize sender here
```

Comment: I did as you proposed. my PostData class hast construtor to pass the JSONString to it so when I put this line `PostData sender = new PostData();` in the onCreate method I am getting this error `he constructor PostData() is undefined` ? I have fourth element in the JSOn string which represents the strongest wifi access point I am getting this value of this element from inner class BoradcastReiceiver in the MainActivity therefore I thought timer and AsyncTask class are better.

Comment: please see my updated code or please update your answer to get the point because I still getting just the same time in the DataPost class.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer: I am getting now the right data but I have two simple question ;) why should I initialize sender `PostData sender = new PostData()` in inCreate methodsince when I did that I got this error `sender cannot be resolved` but when I initialized it outside the MainActivity or in the onLocationChanged mehod it works fine. Second question: it is not better approach in my case to excute the AsyncTask from timer? I want to send the data to the server just if the location changed

Comment: @MrAsker No problem, glad it's working for you now!  I'm not sure why the placement of  `PostData sender = new PostData() ` in `onCreate()` would cause a problem, but as long as it gets initialized before you refrence it, it should be fine.  As for the timer, I think that you can remove all of your Threads and `postDelayed()` calls, and just execute the `AsyncTask` when the `onLocationChanged` callback occurs, as I have outlined in the answer.

Comment: Please can you  take a look at this question here:? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863769/send-latitude-and-longitude-from-the-boadcastreceiver-when-the-internet-connecti