# Send latitude and Longitude from the BoadcastReceiver when the internet connection is available

Tags: android

I want to send JSON String

```
{
    "latitude": 53.86898504,
    "longitude": 10.66561187,
    "time": "25.04.2015 11:37:11",
    "route": 4
}
```

to the server every 60 seconds so  when I try to send the JSON string from my internet connection BroadcastReceiver the JSON string is null there but when I send the data from onLocationChanged method I am getting the string  in the PostData class but I want to send the data just when the internet connection is available if the internet is not available I will store the string for short time. How can I implement it to get the JSONString in the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION BroadcastReceiver?

I appreciate any help.

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Location location;
LocationManager locationManager;
String jSONString;

    TextView textJSON;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textJSON);


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, ll);


    }

    private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                     //code to get the strongest wifi access point in the JSON string the routes's value.
            }

            else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getActiveNetworkInfo();

                boolean isConnected = netInfo != null
                        && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                if (isConnected) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "The device is connected to the internet ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (location == null) {

                    Location locat = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (locat == null) {

                        LocationListener locLis = new myLocationListener();
                        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                        Looper myLooper = Looper.myLooper();

                        locMan.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locLis,
                                myLooper);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("locat is not null");
                    }

                } else {
                    PostData sender = new PostData();
                    sender.timer(jSONString);
                    textJSON.setText(jSONString);
                }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Please connect the device to the internet.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                ...
                String time = sdf.format(location.getTime());

                jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, time);
                System.out.println("The output of onLocationChanged: "+ jSONString);

                //The code works fine here. JSON string has its values here but in broadcastReceiver JSON string has null.
//              PostData sender = new PostData();
//              sender.timer(jSONString);
//              textJSON.setText(jSONString);



            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could get your desired behavior by just adding an extra flag as an instance variable to determine if you got a location update with no internet, and also making the `isConnected` flag an instance variable.

The idea is to send location data every time you get a location changed event if there is a connection to the internet, otherwise set the flag and wait until there is an internet connection to send the data from the last location update.

I took your original code posted in the question and modified it:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int route_number;
    double pLong;
    double pLat;
    String time;
    String jSONString;

    boolean isConnected; //added
    boolean locationUpdatedNoInternet; //added
    long lastLocationTime = 0; //added

    TextView textJSON;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textJSON);


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, ll);


    }

    private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                //code to get the strongest wifi access point in the JSON string the routes's value.
            }

            else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getActiveNetworkInfo();

                //set instance variable isConnected here instead of creating local variable
                isConnected = netInfo != null
                        && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                //boolean isConnected = netInfo != null
                        //&& netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                if (isConnected) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "The device is connected to the internet ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //check if we got a location update with no internet
                    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (locationUpdatedNoInternet == true) {
                        //check that last location send was longer than 5 seconds ago
                        if (lastLocationTime == 0 || ((currTime - lastLocationTime) > 5000 )){
                            lastLocationTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //set last sent time
                            locationUpdatedNoInternet = false; //re-set to false
                            PostData sender = new PostData();
                            //since we are checking locationUpdatedNoInternet flag, we definitely have location data.
                            System.out.println("The output of internet broadcast: " + jSONString);
                            sender.timer(jSONString);
                            textJSON.setText(jSONString);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Please connect the device to the internet.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                pLong = location.getLongitude();
                pLat = location.getLatitude();
                //...
                time = sdf.format(location.getTime());

                jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, time);
                System.out.println("The output of onLocationChanged: "+ jSONString);

                long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (isConnected == true) {
                    //check that last location send was longer than 5 seconds ago
                    if (lastLocationTime == 0 || ((currTime - lastLocationTime) > 5000 )) {
                        //if connected, just send the data
                        lastLocationTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //set last sent time
                        locationUpdatedNoInternet = false;
                        PostData sender = new PostData();
                        sender.timer(jSONString);
                        textJSON.setText(jSONString);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //set flag so that the last location update will be sent once connection is established
                    locationUpdatedNoInternet = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed here with your sulotion  I am getting the output of `sender.timer(jSONString);` twice  at the same time!?  is that because sender.timer(jSOnString) is being called twice in the  `BroadcastReceiverListener` and in the `onLocationChanged()`?

Comment: @MrAsker Yes, that's possible.  You can verify in your logs if that is the case.  A simple solution would be to keep a timestamp of the last update time, and make sure that it's been longer than 5 seconds since the last update.  See updated answer, look at `lastLocationTime` and `currTime`.

Comment: Please can you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292622/the-app-keeps-restarting-itself-automatically

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

1. Whenever BroadCastReceiver triggers you first check for `location`(instance variable) is `null` or not.
2. If `location` is null get location by calling `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` which returns location or null.
3. If `getLastKnownLocation()` return `null` make a single location update request `requestSingleUpdate(Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)` check listener callback.

Comment: but location is undefined in the internet connection  BroadcastReicer. does that mean I schould extend myLocationListener with internet connectionBroafdcastReceiver or it would be better to extend my PostData class?

Comment: Create instance variable (class level) of `Location location` and init its value at `onLocationChanged`.  when BroadCastReceiver trigger check for location instance not jsonString.

Comment: please see my updated question I implemnted it as  you said and I am getting this error:`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.location.Location android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: check location value before you use it `if(location!=null) { }`