# onHandleIntent receiving the fired intent every second instead of every 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I have checkboxlist where the user selectes some items I am envloping his selecting in json format thenI am firing the json string from the alarmManager to the GetLLRD class. Currently I am getting intent in the OnHandleIntent not every 30 second but roughly every second or several times in one second. How can I manage it to get the intent just once every 30 seconds in the onHandleIntent in the GetLLRD class?

**Some of the output:**

```
07-07 17:18:01.817: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:02.828: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:04.049: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:04.810: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:05.821: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:06.822: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:07.822: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:08.843: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:09.824: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:10.835: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:11.876: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 17:18:12.907: I/System.out(6493): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
```

**MainActivity class:**

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        GetLLRD.class);
                intent.putExtra("json_data", json);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 3,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
                startService(intent);
```

**GetLLRD class:**

```
public class GetLLRD extends IntentService {

    public GetLLRD() {
        super("IntentService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        System.out.println("test from the onHandleIntent" + jSONString);
        if(jSONString != null){

            System.out.println("Test");
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to receive the intent in the `IntentReceiver` then I am getting it every 30 seconds but in the onHandleIntent I am receiving it too quick as I mentioned earlier.

**IntentReceiver:**

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");

            if (!action.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("test from IntentReiceier" + action);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Alarm manager is firing only the broadcast not starring the service. How are you getting the call to onHandleIntent method. Please post your entire activity code

Comment: I just have this psrt of code in the MainActivity I thought it is being started when there is intent. How can I then start the onHanleIntent method in the GetLLRD class IntentService?

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent .getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 3, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); here intent is created with service class but you are using getbroadcast method to get pending intent which is wrong. You should use get service method. Please change code accordingly and try.

Comment: I have tried it but I am still getting the inetent too quick every second.

Comment: Use System.currentTimeMillis() I stead of calendar instance in setrepeating method and try

Comment: ham now I am receiving the intent every 10 seconds although I changed the interval to 50 seconds. Is it possible to start the HttpURLConnection from the BroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: Its possible but Not recommended

Comment: I habe tried to put my code of the HttpURLConnection inside the onReceive() method but I got `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` I have tried this code before in the doInBackground method and it works. I dont have any problem with the internet connection since I have another AsnycTask classes in my app which are getting reponses from the server so I dont know why I am getting this kind of error in the IntentReceiver class?

Comment: @TheBook I just tested your code, and I'm getting `onHandleIntent()` in the IntentService called every 30 seconds as expected.  I'm using your code exactly as posted (and I also tested it using `getService()` instead of `getBroadcast`).  There must be something else going on in code not posted in your question.

Comment: @DanielNugent: have you tested it with the `BroadcastReceiver ` or without it? Also  have you interlinked the alarmManager with `BroadcastReceiver ` and then from it sent the intent to the IntentService or have you sent the intent directly from the alarmManager to the GetLLRD class?

Comment: @TheBook I just ran it with the IntentService, with the exact code from your first two code blocks.

Comment: It works now I  deleted my app from the device then installed it again now I am getting what I want thanks for your support :)

Comment: @TheBook Sure, no problem! Glad it's working for you now!