# Send a request to the server when closing the app to delete the related data

Tags: android, networking

I want to sent a request with the mac address from the Android app to the server when the app is being closed to delete all data of the mac in the database tables but I am facing problem that I can not start the IntentService from the onDestroy(). I can not place the code inside the onPause() or onStart() since I just want to sent the request once when the app is being closed. Therefor I placed it within the ´onDestroy()´ method but on the other hand, it does not allow to start the service inside it.

Does soneome have a solution for my problem? How can I send a request to the server to clear data in the tables related to the mac address?

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    System.out.println("JsonObject" + jsonObject);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            ClearTable.class);
    intent2.putExtra("json_mac", json);
    startService(intent2);
      }
```

**IntentService:**

```
public class ClearTable extends IntentService{

    public ClearTable() {
        super("IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_mac");
            System.out.println("xyz The output of : doInBackground "
                    + jSONString);
            URL myUrl = new URL(
                    "https://serverside-apple.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();             
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();             
            System.out.println("xyz The output of getResponsecode: "
             + conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".ClearTable" />
```

Comment: Why should you delete data ?  You can't achieve it because you can't be sure that  some method will be called will app be killed.

Comment: @tinysunlight:  I am implementing an app to visualize the  bus location in Google maps based on Crowd sourcing in my city . So when the rider closes the app then I have to send a request to the server to deleted the data related to this rider. Would be an opption to create a dialog to ask the user if he is sure he wants to close the app then if he tappes YES then it is poosiable to send this request but I think it is bad strategy otherwise how to delete the bus location related to this rider if he closes the app?

Comment: people may kill your app by tasklist or  your app may be kill by system.You may create a long link with rider.per second send you sth. if they don't send msg to you in serval seconds , you remove them.

Comment: @tinysunlight: What do you with long link? Sorry but  I did not get your point :(.

Comment: Just send msg to server per serval seconds.