# How to test Location Services in AndroidTest using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am trying to perform Mock Location tests in androidTest, but unfortunately, I am not getting the callback at all for OnLocationChanged. I have searched a lot on web but did not get any valid/useful response. Below are the links which I have tried:

https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/

[Android mock location on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)

Below is the code which I am trying.

Location TestCase

public class LocationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

```
Activity context;
MockLocationProvider mock;


Object lock = new Object();

public LocationTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    context = getActivity();
}

public void testLocation() throws InterruptedException {
    mock = new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, context);

    //Set test location
    mock.pushLocation(-12.34, 23.45);

    LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener lis = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //You will get the mock location
            Log.d("LocationTest", location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("LocationTest", provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("LocationTest", provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("LocationTest", provider);
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lis);

    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.wait(60 * 1000);
    }

}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mock.shutdown();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

}

Mock Location Provider
public class MockLocationProvider {

```
String providerName;
Context ctx;

public MockLocationProvider(String name, Context ctx) {
    this.providerName = name;
    this.ctx = ctx;

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false,
            true, true, 0, 5);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
}

public void pushLocation(double lat, double lon) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location mockLocation = new Location(providerName);
    mockLocation.setLatitude(lat);
    mockLocation.setLongitude(lon);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(0);
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mockLocation.setAccuracy(0.0f);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }
    mockLocation.setAltitude(0.0f);
    lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, mockLocation);
}

public void shutdown() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.removeTestProvider(providerName);
}
```

}

Please let me know If anybody has any clue or idea to test LocationService in androidTest.

Thanks,
Nishant