# How to modify Gps data for test in a real Android-powered device

Tags: android, location, android-location

There are [3 ways](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html?#MockData) to modify Gps data in the Android emulator.
But how can I do this in a real Android-powered device in order to test the location function.

Comment: Use a Mock Location Provider on device: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2531317/295004

Answer (score 0):

You can try fake GPS:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.fakegps.fre&hl=en

or you can use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

in mandifest and customize your code with [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) with detail in

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/how-to-mock-location-on-device)

I hope it can help your problem!